# React Redux Fast Update State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How to update the state just after dispatch?

State should be updated but is not.

What should be changed? Even when we will use then in our code -> even then we will not receive updated state, only when we will take value from the like .then((value) => { value.data }), but I want to take data from the state

Slice Code:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(activateUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.userData
      })
  },
})

export const activateUser = createAsyncThunk('auth/activate', async (data) => {
  try {
    const userData = await authService.activateAccount(data)
    return { userData: userData.data.data }
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()
    return message
  }
})

const { reducer } = authSlice
export default reducer
```

Component:

```
function ActivateAccount() {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  const [code, setCode] = useState('')
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const activateUserAccount = () => {
    const data = {
      code: code?.value,
      userId: user?._id,
      email: user?.email || email?.value,
    }

    dispatch(activateUser(data))
    console.log('Why here value is not updated yet?', user)
    if (!user.activated) {
      setCode({
        ...code,
        isNotActivated: true,
      })
      return
    }

    return navigate('/on-board')
  }
 
}
```

Why in the console log value is not yet updated?

What should be changed?

Any ideas?

Comment: put the logic staring from the console.log() inside a `useEffect(()=> {},[user])` method. You can't expect that the user is changed directly after the dispatch().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it's Redux it still needs to work within the confines of the React component lifecycle. In other words, the state needs to be updated and subscribers notified and React to rerender with the updated state. You are currently logging the `user` state closed over in function scope of the current render cycle. There's no possible way to log what the state will be on any subsequent render cycle.

You can chain from the asynchronous action though, and check any resolved values.

```
function ActivateAccount() {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const activateUserAccount = () => {
    const data = {
      code: code?.value,
      userId: user?._id,
      email: user?.email || email?.value,
    }

    dispatch(activateUser(data))
      .unwrap()
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        if (!user.activated) {
          setCode(code => ({
            ...code,
            isNotActivated: true,
          }));
          return;
        }

        return navigate('/on-board');
      });
  }

  ...
}
```